# Dividing elements in two arrays with Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, division

I have two arrays of:

```
x=43035000 51065000 67085000 36770000 57165000 54335000 46590000 64410000 39295000 37210000 41800000
y=397 420 349 300 387 417 365 567 321 314 341
```

I would like to divide the first number in x with the first number in y and the second number in x with the second number in y and so on...

I have tried:

```
for i in "${x[@]}"; do for j in "${y[@]}"; do awk "{print $i/$j}"; done; done
```

however it just lists the numbers in x and then the numbers in y:

```
43035000
51065000
67085000
36770000
57165000
54335000
46590000
64410000
39295000
37210000
41800000
397
420
349
300
387
417
365
567
321
314
341
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to use parens to declare your arrays.

```
x=( 43035000 51065000 67085000 36770000 57165000 54335000 46590000 64410000 39295000 37210000 41800000 )
y=(      397      420      349      300      387      417      365      567      321      314      341 )
```

An alternate syntax -

```
$: for i in ${!x[@]}; do echo "${x[i]} ${y[i]}"; done | awk '{print $1/$2}'
108401
121583
192221
122567
147713
130300
127644
113598
122414
118503
```

For any array `foo`, `${!foo[@]}` returns a list of the indexes/keys.
So long as `x` & `y` have the same indexes/keys, this should work fine.

You could also load your arrays into files of their own and just let awk handle all of it...

```
$: cat x
43035000
51065000
67085000
36770000
57165000
54335000
46590000
64410000
39295000
37210000
41800000

$: cat y
397
420
349
300
387
417
365
567
321
314
341

$: awk 'NR==FNR{ dividend[FNR]=$1 } NR>FNR{ print dividend[FNR]/$1 }' x y
108401
121583
192221
122567
147713
130300
127644
113598
122414
118503
122581
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both arrays contain the same number of elements and all elements are numeric, you can use a C-style `for` loop in `bash`:

```
x=(43035000 51065000 67085000 36770000 57165000 54335000 46590000 64410000 39295000 37210000 41800000)
y=(397 420 349 300 387 417 365 567 321 314 341)
for ((i=0; i<${#x[@]}; ++i)); do echo "${x[i]} ${y[i]}"; done |
    awk '{print $1/$2}'
```

Or, if all you need is integer truncated division, you can use shell arithmetic (you don't need `awk` in this case):

```
for ((i=0; i<${#x[@]}; ++i)); do echo $((x[i] / y[i])); done
```

Note that this second solution won't work if numerator or denominator isn't integer or you want a floating-point result.

Comment: Could also write `for i in "${!x[@]}"` to iterate over the indices.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass variable to awk like this

```
$ x=(43035000 51065000 67085000 36770000 57165000 54335000 46590000 64410000 39295000 37210000 41800000)
$ y=(397 420 349 300 387 417 365 567 321 314 341)

$ for (( i=0; i<${#x[@]}; i++ )); 
do 
    awk -v I=${x[$i]} -v J=${y[$i]} 'BEGIN{print I / J}';
done
```

Comment: You are dividing all Xs with all Ys: `X[1]/Y[1], X[2]/Y[1], X[3]/Y[1]`, this is not what the author wants: he or she wants `X[1]/Y[1], X[2]/Y[2], X[3]/Y[3]`, ...

Comment: Also, this calls `awk` repeatedly. Just use the pipe.

Comment: It is just his approach tweaked to work how he wanted. This whole thing could be easily done in pure `AWK`, or just `shell`.